# Javascript: Add multiple Lighthbox galleries on same page

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox, multiple-instances

I am using a modified version of light house from this [page.](http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/example2.html)
I want to add two instances of the same code to add two differrent slideshows on the same page. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [6th example](http://www.electricprism.com/aeron/slideshow/example6.html) on same page you linked to

Comment: Got it working individually! 
I just coppied the script codes with a different name and calld that div id.
But in some Browsers like Google Chrome the mouse over controls don't go away.

Comment: Did you set the `controller: false` option?

Comment: If I do that the controller will never appear.